# Why UuidFromString function requests non-const pointer to unsigned char?

Tags: c++, winapi, constants

I have no idea why [UuidFromString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function requered **non-const** pointer to **unsigned** char. Why not `const char*` instead?

My thoughts that there is no need to data modification pointed by the first argument.

Comment: Perhaps to dis-allow passing string literals?

Comment: @vsoftco: why should that be a problem?

Comment: @MatteoItalia Frankly I don't know what this function does, was just a wild guess. But it shouldn't return pointers to temporaries (I thought that maybe it just returns the passed pointer somehow).

Comment: @vsoftco: it's just a function that parses the string representation of a UUID and writes the parsed value to a UUID structure, returning a status code to signal if the conversion couldn't be performed. I really cannot think of a reason why it needs a non-const buffer for input, probably it was an oversight.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thanks! Yes, then I agree, doesn't make any sense otherwise.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think that's quite an old function.  `const` may not have been well-supported at the time.  Many older Windows API functions don't use it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston what do you think about `unsigned` instead of plain `char`?

Comment: Perhaps for consistency with the UUID structure?  That's a wild guess, though.  I have no idea.

Comment: @HarryJohnston according to this documentation this function first appeared in Windows 2000 (but const has been around since the first ANSI C at least). It seems more likely to me that it was just poorly designed , perhaps by an old timer who thought const-correctness was rubbish new-fangled junk

Comment: @M.M: the MSDN documentation doesn't actually keep track of when a function first became available.  Whenever a page is updated, the "minimum supported version" is changed to the earliest version of Windows still in support.  (So for example if they updated that page today, they would change it to read "Windows Vista".)

Comment: @HarryJohnston OK.  COM was introduced with Windows 95 though, which still would seem to be in the window when const was available. I guess back then standard conformance wasn't really a priority and people coded for the particular compiler they were using.

Comment: @M.M. I was thinking it might have been available on some but not all of the compilers they needed to support.  But Zac's answer points out that UuidToString, presumably introduced at the same time, *did* use const, so that pretty much puts paid to that theory. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`UuidFromString` was designed for COM/DCOM.

The `unsigned char` is to prevent the need to check for negative `char` values (the default `char` is `signed`, meaning the values ranged [-128, 127] - since this string is supposed to be ANSI characters, it is a cheap way to avoid having a `< 0` conditional check).

Its sister function (`UuidToString`) does take a `const` input parameter.  I do not see a reason in the documentation as to why `UuidFromString` does not as well, but it is likely an oversight that was never addressed.